# Reads a file containing 10 data items that populate the array create in struct and Displays the contents of the array after it has been populated

Tags: c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkCDG.png)

the original question attached. I am stuck populating the file into the array and then displaying it. the file only has 10 numbers. this is in c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
const int SIZE = 10;

struct stemp{
   int stud_id_num;
   int num_credit_completed;
   double cum_gpa;

 }stemp[SIZE];



ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("stemp.txt");

int count = 0;
 while(!inputFile.eof()){
     inputFile >> stemp[SIZE];
 }


 inputFile.close();


return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several mistakes here

First `while(!inputFile.eof()) {` is not the correct way to read until the end of file. It should be `while (inputFile >> ...) {`

Second `inputFile >> stemp[SIZE];` reads into `stemp[10]` but your array is only size 10, so `stemp[10]` doesn't exist. What you probably meant was

```
inputFile >> stemp[count];
count++;
```

That way each read goes into a different element of the array, depending on the value of the `count` variable.

Putting that together you have

```
int count = 0;
while (inputFile >> stemp[count]) {
    count++;
}
```

That loop is now correct, but I'm afraid your biggest mistake is yet to come. You see `inputFile >> stemp[count]` isn't going to work. C++ doesn't magically know how to read your file into your structure. You have to write the code to do that. You have to write a version of `>>` that works with your file and your structure.

In other words you have to write this

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, stemp& s)
{
    // code to read s from in goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

*stemp.txt*

```
1 2 2.1
3 4 3.2
5 6 5.3
7 8 7.4
9 10 11.5
11 12 13.6
13 14 17.7
15 16 19.8
17 18 23.9
19 20 27.10
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t SIZE = 10;

struct stemp
{
    int id;
    int credits;
    double cum_gpa;
};

void printStemp(stemp const& s, int const& index)
{
    printf(
        "Stemp %d\nid: %d\ncredits: %d\ncum_gpa: %.2f\n\n",
        index, s.id, s.credits, s.cum_gpa
    );
}

int main()
{
    stemp arr[SIZE];

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("stemp.txt");

    if (inputFile.fail())
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        inputFile >> arr[i].id >> arr[i].credits >> arr[i].cum_gpa;

    inputFile.close();

    cout << "Displaying content:\n\n";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printStemp(arr[i], i);

    return 0;
}
```